# How to add first option as default option in select ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui Select for dropdown. I want to set first option as default selected when page loads. However, I am not able to find any documentation.

```
<Select

  open={open}
  className={classes.select}
  onClose={this.handleClose}
  onOpen={this.handleOpen}
  value={brand}
  onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)}
  name="brand"
  inputProps={inputProps}>

  {data.getBrands.map(brands => 
   <MenuItem key={brands.id} 
            value={brands.originalId} 
            id{brands.originalId}>{brands.name}
   </MenuItem>)}

</Select>
```

I expect the dropdown to contain to first option as default value when page loads for first time.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to assign the first value of `data.getBrands` into the `brand` variable before rendering `Select` component. Something like this:

```
...
brand = data.getBrands.length > 0 ? data.getBrands[0].originalId : '';
...
<Select
  open={open}
  className={classes.select}
  onClose={this.handleClose}
  onOpen={this.handleOpen}
  value={brand} // this will select the first option after page load
  onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)}
  name="brand"
  inputProps={inputProps}>

  {data.getBrands.map(brands => 
   <MenuItem key={brands.id} 
            value={brands.originalId} 
            id{brands.originalId}>{brands.name}
   </MenuItem>)}
</Select>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your valuable solution but this is not  working.

Comment: @PoojaThapa sorry i did not notice `brand` is an object and `brand.originalId` is the actual value. So you need to assign `data.getBrands[0].originalId` instead of `data.getBrands[0]` to get your desired result. I've edited my answer. Try and let me know.